# Can the Primary Key of a SQLite table have a custom default value?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I cannot find any documentation that says you cannot have a DEFAULT value on a PRIMARY KEY field. However my experiments with this test code do not pan out. It is accepted as valid, but just generates values of (n+1). It works fine for non primary key fields.

```
CREATE Table A (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY default(random())
)
```

Is this possible?

Comment: the primary key is, must be, unique for each row. So a default value is nonsensical. Also, generating random numbers (never mind "primary key") is not guaranteed to be unique. In fact it's probable there will be repeated values.

Comment: This is purely an example for simplicity to illustrate the question. It isn't intended to be practical.

Comment: Hmm, well ok let me throw out a few random thoughts.. As a technical definition a primary key is unique in a table. A key may consist of multiple columns - as long as that "compound key" is unique - some row's key column may have duplicate values, but as long as the complete compound key is unique, that's fine. Finally, also realize that primary keys are not required in a table.

Comment: An example of when a default value is useful is when you want to use the current timestamp as the primary key: `CreatedAt INTEGER PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT (STRFTIME('%s', 'now'))`. This works if the creation of records is guaranteed to be spread far enough in time to avoid duplicate values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`integer primary key` is a sort of a keyword in SQlite that is an alias of `rowid`, and SQlite will silently ignore your default if you provide one.

So you have two solutions:

1. Create a table without `rowid`

   ```
   create table A (id integer primary key default(random())) without rowid;
   ```
2. Declare `id` as something that is an integer primary key, without using the "keyword" `integer primary key`, for example by replacing `integer` with `int`:

   ```
   create table A (id int primary key default(random()));
   ```

On whether or not you want to take the `without rowid` route, you could read [this section](https://sqlite.org/withoutrowid.html) of the documentation.

Comment: I thought your first solution held promise looking at the documentation for it. However when tried, both solutions still return (n+1) in the field. Did you get a different result?

Comment: Yes, both works by me. Which version of SQlite do you have?

Comment: Huh. Ok, now I have both your solutions working. The problem turned out to be the SQLite interface I was using 'DB Browser for SQLite' - or at least the way I was using it to test this scenario. I was creating the table, then adding rows to it with the GUI 'New Record' button. For some reason that always adds rows (n+1). When I switched to inserting test rows by typing SQL inserts, both these default value solutions started working.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `autoincrement`:

```
CREATE Table A (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
);
```

Strictly speaking this is not necessary, because SQLite has a built-in `rowid`.

Comment: While true, this is not where I was going with this question. I have edited the question to make it more specific.